# How to refresh the content of a grid continiously from the code behind file

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I try to refresh the content of my grid continiously with a parallel thread. Thats the code which is not working:

```
private void ContiniouslyRefreshPage(int interval)
        {
            var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
            var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(interval);           
            Dictionary<string, string> lastCheck = bluetoothService.CheckRequirements();
            var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> newCheck = bluetoothService.CheckRequirements();
                if (!(lastCheck.Count == newCheck.Count && !bluetoothService.CheckRequirements().Except(lastCheck).Any()))
                {
                    Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetail
                    {
                        Detail = new NavigationPage(new TestingPage())
                        {
                            BarBackgroundColor = Color.White,
                            BarTextColor = Color.Black
                        }
                    };
                    lastCheck = newCheck;
                }
            }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
        }
```

The if-clause works, so the page should only refesh when there is a change of my dataset (dataset is returned by CheckRequirements-Method)

The code is not working: It gets into the if-clause when there is a change but it doesn't initialize and display the new Page.

I think this is not the best practise at all, i'd like to have an advice how to do it better.

Comment: why are you replacing the ENTIRE page stack just to modify the contents of a single page?

Comment: Because only the Thread that created a view can modify it. So I cant open a new Thread that checks every 3 seconds for changes and the access out of this Thread the views that the "main"-Thread created.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The updating UI opeation should be executed in the main thread. Try to put the related function code in the main thread. Such as: `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>{// Code to run on the main thread});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updating UI opeation should be executed in the main thread. Try to put the related function code in the main thread. Such as:

```
private void ContiniouslyRefreshPage(int interval)
{
    ...
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new MasterDetail
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage(new TestingPage())
            {
                BarBackgroundColor = Color.White,
                BarTextColor = Color.Black
            }
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to mention it: @Jason was right in criticising loading the whole new Page. I just called a method that changes the values in the Grid within the Main Thread.